# Cannot generate apk in release mode

Tags: android, android-studio

I was following this documentation "Configure the build process to automatically sign your app" https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-auto and trying to generate apk for release version.

However, the apk that is generated always locate inside `debug` folder even though I did setting for release on Module Setting.

This is `gradle` file.

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'key0'
        keyPassword 'password'
        storeFile file('C:/path/to/filename.jks')
        storePassword 'password'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.packagename"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 3
    versionName "2.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
}
```

[image]

and I clicked `Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)` -> `Build APK(s)`

Is this what it supposed to do? If not, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android studio click on `Build variant` option on left vertical bar and then select `release Build variant` then `Build Bundle(s)/APK(s) -> Build APK(s)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks seems like it is trying to generate `apk` for release even though there is still error.